# Error while upgrading apache tomcat server from 7.0 to 8.5.5, check whether you have multiple ContextLoader*

Tags: spring, apache, hibernate, tomcat

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.appfuse.webapp.listener.StartupListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:277)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.appfuse.webapp.listener.StartupListener.contextInitialized(StartupListener.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: show your `web.xml`, error states there are more than 1 `ContextLoader`

Comment: I have Upgraded Hibernate to version 4.3.5, Spring to version 4.1.3, site working fine using tomcat v7.0.91, Error is when i upgrade the tomcat server to 8.5.5.